# 'Libwine:i386' error when I apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dpkg, wine, x86

`apt-get upgrade` shows the following error;

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: 
files list file for package 'libwine:i386' is missing final newline
E: Sub-processs /usr/bin/dpkg returned  an error code (2)
```

Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcbNc.jpg)

Please how do I fix this?

Comment: Please run these commands and update the question with output 1. `dpkg --configure -a` 2. `apt-get update` 3. `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Tried it but still getting the error

Comment: `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libwine:i386.list` and `sudo apt-get clean` then`try to reinstall the package.